# Получение данных (событий) из БД в fullCalendar (node.js)

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js, плагин, calendar

Есть такое представление. Каким образом можно отобразить здесь события, добавленные в БД, с помощью `node` и `fullcalendar`?

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'marionette',
  'fullcalendar',
  'localefullcalendar'
], function($, Mn) {
  'use strict';

  return Mn.ItemView.extend({
    className: 'calendar',
    template: false,

    onShow: function() {
      this.showCalendar();
    },

    showCalendar: function() {
      this.$el.fullCalendar({
        //url: 'D:\web\copy\msserver\js\config.js',
        //color: 'yellow',   // an option!
        //            textColor: 'yellow',
        //                events: [
        //                    {
        //                        title: 'AllDayAllDayAllDayAllDayAllDay',
        //                        start: '2017-04-26'
        //                    },
        //                    
        //                ],
        locale: 'ru',
      });
    },
  });
});
```